# 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

There are similar questions out addressing a similar concern but they do not appear to fix my issue. Please note that this project does not have any errors when using VS 2012.

I have a project that was built using MVC 3. I want to use VS 2013 to continue to work on this project but I get many errors that start with this text -'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for... I found on [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18612) why I believe I am getting the error. VS 2013 is trying to use MVC 4 or 5 instead of 3. Within the web.config file I have the following assemblies and settings which should explicitly set the correct version.

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</assemblies>
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
</appSettings>
```

When I run the project it runs fine but my intellisense is showing errors () on all items that use the System.Web.WebPages reference. I have deleted the following references and made sure to reimport the correct versions (System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.Helpers, System.Web.WebPages).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have Resharper installed? I have encountered this when the Resharper system cache is out of sync.

Comment: No ReSharper installed, but thank you anyways.

Comment: are your References and web.config agreeing with each other? have you tried cleaning your solution?

Comment: When I build the project all of my references show without any errors and the assemblies in the web.config match the reference versions that I have. The project does not have any intellisense errors when I open it in VS 2012. Cleaning the solution did not fix the issue.

Comment: Issue is now fixed... had to remove MVC through Nuget manager and reinstalled latest version MVC 5.2.3. Had to add key value into the web.config within the Views folder for the webpages version.